# I want to use the "go" keyword to run 2 queries one after the other so as to save my time in montoring whether the query has got completed or not

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to use the "go" keyword to run 2 queries one after the other so as to save my time in montoring whether the query has got completed or not.

Currently I'm using this syntax:

```
select count(*) from ABC
go
select count(*) from XYZ
```

THIS IS THROWING AN ERROR.

Please suggest the correct syntax

If there is no provision to run multiple queries one after the other using "go" keyword please suggest an alternative.

Comment: Running from where - a client like SQL*Plus/SQL Developer, or from an application?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select count(*) from ABC;
select count(*) from XYZ;
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b13c/2

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using semicolons after your queries.

```
select count(*) from ABC;
go;
select count(*) from XYZ;
```